# JAXB apply bindings to more than one .xsd schema

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2, xjc, jaxb2-basics

I have several XML schemas over which I do not have control and I'd like to apply certain customizations when generating the Java classes via XJC.

Some customizations should apply to all `.xsd` files, but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

At the moment I have this `.xjb` file:

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.1" 
  xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance"
  jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="inheritance">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../schemas/A.xsd">
         <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="my.foo.a" />
        </jxb:schemaBindings> 

        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='A']">
            <jxb:class name="A" />
            <inheritance:implements>my.foo.interfaces.IA</inheritance:implements>           
         </jxb:bindings>

         <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='Device']">
            <jxb:class name="Device" />
            <inheritance:implements>my.foo.interfaces.IDevice</inheritance:implements>          
         </jxb:bindings>             
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../schemas/B.xsd">        
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="my.foo.b" />
        </jxb:schemaBindings>

        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='B']">
            <jxb:class name="B" />
            <inheritance:implements>my.foo.interfaces.IB</inheritance:implements>       
         </jxb:bindings>

        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='Device']">
            <jxb:class name="Device" />
            <inheritance:implements>my.foo.interfaces.IDevice</inheritance:implements>          
         </jxb:bindings>             
    </jxb:bindings>      
</jxb:bindings>
```

And this Ant task:

```
<taskdef name="xjc" classname="org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.xjc.XJC2Task">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="../../dependencies/lib" >
            <include name="activation-*.jar"/>
            <include name="jaxb-api-*.jar"/>
            <include name="jaxb-impl-*.jar"/>
            <include name="jsr173_api-*.jar"/>
            <include name="stax-api-*.jar"/>

            <include name="jaxb2-basics-jaxb-xjc-*.jar"/>
            <include name="jaxb-xjc-*.jar"/>
            <include name="jaxb2-basics-ant-*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<xjc destdir="../src" extension="true" header="false" binding="bindings.xjb">
    <arg line="-Xinheritance"/>

    <schema dir="../schemas">
        <include name="*.xsd"/>
        <exclude name="Foo.xsd"/>
    </schema>

    <!-- Plugins -->
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="../../dependencies/lib">
            <!-- JAXB2 Basics library -->
            <include name="jaxb2-basics-*.jar"/>
            <!-- JAXB2 Basics library dependencies -->
            <include name="jaxb2-basics-runtime-*.jar"/>
            <include name="jaxb2-basics-tools-*.jar"/>
            <include name="javaparser-*.jar"/>
            <include name="commons-beanutils-*.jar"/>
            <include name="commons-lang-*.jar"/>
            <include name="commons-logging-*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </classpath>
</xjc>
```

Finally what I would like to do is to somehow specify the common blocks (of which I have more than one), ie:

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='Device']">
    <jxb:class name="Device" />
    <inheritance:implements>my.foo.interfaces.IDevice</inheritance:implements>          
</jxb:bindings>
```

For all of my `.xsd` files.

Hypothetically, something like this:

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.1" 
  xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance"
  jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="inheritance">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../schemas/*.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='Device']">
            <jxb:class name="Device" />
            <inheritance:implements>my.foo.interfaces.IDevice</inheritance:implements>          
        </jxb:bindings>  
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../schemas/A.xsd">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="my.foo.a" />
        </jxb:schemaBindings> 

        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='A']">
            <jxb:class name="A" />
            <inheritance:implements>my.foo.interfaces.IA</inheritance:implements>           
        </jxb:bindings>           
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../schemas/B.xsd">        
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="my.foo.b" />
        </jxb:schemaBindings>

        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='B']">
            <jxb:class name="B" />
            <inheritance:implements>my.foo.interfaces.IB</inheritance:implements>       
        </jxb:bindings>       
    </jxb:bindings>      
</jxb:bindings>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, for (the most part) using this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18592030/770023

I have managed to get the schema working, for reference all you need to do is set `schemaLocation="*"` (in order to read all the schemas, of course) and mark the binding elements with `multiple="true"` and `required="false"` since some schemas may contain those elements (one or more times), some may not contain them at all.

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.1" 
  xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance"
  jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="inheritance">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="*">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='Device']" multiple="true" required="false">
            <inheritance:implements>my.foo.interfaces.IDevice</inheritance:implements>          
        </jxb:bindings>  
    </jxb:bindings>
    <!-- rest of the bindings (per schema ones) go here -->
</jxb:bindings>
```

Please note that for some (unknown to me) reason I had to remove the `class` bindings (eg. `<jxb:class name="Device" />`) for the file to be accepted by XJC.

It mostly works, what I haven't been able to get working is the `inheritance:extends` customization, which doesn't want to run under the same conditions as the `implements` one...

Comment: Did you find documentation for the `schemaLocation="*"` somewhere?